# Number of Mondays, Tuesdays, etc.. in a given month in C++

Tags: c++

I have been able to retrieve the first day of any given month, and I also know how many days are in that month. How do i calculate the amount of mondays, tuesdays, etc.. left in the month? Below is my code is far.

```
//Set Days in Month
if(Time.Month == 2)
    {
    if((Time.Year % 400 == 0) || ((Time.Year % 4 == 0) && (Time.Year % 100 != 0)))
        Weekend_Status.Month_Days[Time.Month] = 29;
    else    
        Weekend_Status.Month_Days[Time.Month] = 28;
    }
else if(Time.Month == 1 || Time.Month == 3 || Time.Month == 5 || Time.Month == 7 || Time.Month == 8 || Time.Month == 10 || Time.Month == 12)
    {
    Weekend_Status.Month_Days[Time.Month] = 31;
    }
else
    {
    Weekend_Status.Month_Days[Time.Month] = 30;
    }

//Set New Month Start Day
if(Time.Day == 1 && Time.Hour == 0 && Time.Minute == 0 && Time.Second == 1)
    {
    switch(Time.Day_of_Week)
        {
        case 0: //Sunday
            Weekend_Status.Month_Start_Day = 0;
            break;
        case 1: //Monday
            Weekend_Status.Month_Start_Day = 1;
            break;
        case 2: //Tuesday
            Weekend_Status.Month_Start_Day = 2;
            break;
        case 3: //Wednesday
            Weekend_Status.Month_Start_Day = 3;
            break;
        case 4: //Thursday
            Weekend_Status.Month_Start_Day = 4;
            break;
        case 5: //Friday
            Weekend_Status.Month_Start_Day = 5;
            break;
        case 6: //Saturday
            Weekend_Status.Month_Start_Day = 6;
            break;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Why are you posting the code you claim is working?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie He is not implying that?

Comment: Please add a main and code to address your objective. What can't be seen can not be addressed.
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rietty The OP might as well as posted an empty, do nothing function, [similar to this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4128c829644e3f9).  We shouldn't care if the code to get the month and the number of days in the month works.  That's just unnecessary noise.  If code is to be posted, it should reflect the attempt of what is being asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where you take advantage of the modulo operator, using it to count all days in the month where the day occurs.    Note: Untested.

```
    // example: count how many Wednesdays
    int search_day = 3; 
    int search_day_count = 0;
    int start_day = Weekend_Status.Month_Start_Day;
    int end_day = Weekend_Status.Month_Days[Time.Month];

    // loop through all days for the given month
    for (int day = start_day; day <= start_day + end_day; day++)
    {
        // count all days that are 7 days apart starting from search_day = 3
        if (day == search_day || (day - search_day) % 7 == 0)
        {
            search_day_count++;
        }
    }
```